# Kivy FileChooser: List directories only

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, kivy, filechooser

How to list **only** directories in Kivy FileChooser? I've read about callback filters, but didn't found any examples.

My *Kv* code:

```
<Saveto>:
    select: select
    chooser: chooser
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FileChooserIconView:
        id: chooser
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        rootpath: home
        dirselect: True
        filters: ['How to list folders only?']
    Button:
        ...select button...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

from os.path import join, isdir

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    FileChooserListView:
        filters: [root.is_dir]
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def is_dir(self, directory, filename):
        return isdir(join(directory, filename))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Note that the property is called `filters`, not `filter`, because it's a list, for example, a list of callbacks.

Comment: Window opens and closes immediately for me, is that solution outdated?

Comment: Works for me in Linux. Any errors in the console log?

Comment: Just "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)", nothing useful in the logs. Using Windows 10 64 bits

Comment: Nah.. not getting any error output in the log, just an exit code. The log shows up as a normal application where nothing wrong happened

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in KV directly:

```
<Saveto>:
    select: select
    chooser: chooser
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FileChooserIconView:
        id: chooser
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        rootpath: home
        dirselect: True
        filters: [lambda folder, filename: not filename.endswith('')]
    Button:
        ...select button...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the directory without any file on it you can use:

```
os.path.dirname(filename)
```

in the following way (example where the directory is just used to print the directory as a label in the right side of the screen):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os


Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    FileChooserIconView:
        filters: [root.selected]
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: mypath
            text: ''
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def selected(self, directory, filename):
        self.ids.mypath.text = os.path.dirname(filename)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but seems to work and can be done in the kv file only:

```
dirselect: True
filters: ['']
```

Only folders are shown in FileChooser.